# Unable to import scrapy package

Tags: python, installation

I'm trying to use scrapy in some code. However, I am getting the error from Visual Studio Code:

`Unable to import 'scrapy'pylint(import-error)`.

I think the answer to this is quite simple, but I can't figure it out.

After using `pip install scrapy`, I opened a Python console, imported scrapy, and then used `scrapy.__ file __` to find the directory of the module.

I got: `/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/__ init __.pyc`.

I checked my `sys.path` and it does already include `/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages` already. What's wrong?

Comment: Are you getting the error only inside the VS Code editor, or do you actually get an error when you run the script? If you only get it inside VS Code, then you might have forgotten to set the correct Python interpreter in the VS Code settings.

Comment: I think that's it! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that was simple. As [Azer mentions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56535798/unable-to-import-scrapy-package/56535856#comment99654240_56535798):

> If you only get it inside VS Code, then you might have forgotten to set the correct Python interpreter in the VS Code settings.

Looks like it was just the Python interpreter on VS Code.